# My app is approved by amazon, but shown incompatible when I install using kindle fire hd

Tags: android, kindle-fire

My App is a Cordova app(Cordova 3.2.0-0.1.0), I installed and test it at Kindle fire by ADB

My app is been approved in amazon store, and I can search and install it in my android device, except all Kindle Fire tablet.
It's shown my app is incompatible this device ..
I checked [03-pre-submission-assessment-guide](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/support/submitting-your-app/tech-docs/03-pre-submission-assessment-guide) and not help...

Below is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.myapp.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:allowBackup="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: create layout-hdpi for kindle fire hd. I hope It will helpful

Comment: what's the app? Is it using any Google specific services?

Comment: it's a cordova app, not using any google specific services.